# What was my mistake? (computing complex line integral)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration

Are we not allowed to start questions with the word 'hello'?

None the less, hello. Here $\gamma$ is a counterclockwise circle of radius $r>0$ with centre $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the following integral. $\int_\gamma \text{Re}\big((z-z_0)^n\big)dz$. This is how I computed it, but I know that my answer is wrong. What is my mistake? I DO NOT want the solution to be given to me. I only want my mistake pointed out.

Define $f: \mathbb{C} - \{z_0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=(z-z_0)^n$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{z_0\}$. We parameterize $\gamma$ via the map $w:[0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $w(t)=z_0 + re^{it}$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. Let
\begin{align*}
    I_0 &= \int_\gamma f(z) dz,\\
    I_1 &= \int_\gamma \text{Re}(f(z))dz,\\
    I_2 &= \int_\gamma \text{Im}(f(z))dz.
\end{align*}
We want to compute $I_1$. We will show $I_1 = 0$. Note that
\begin{align*}
    I_0 &=I_1 + iI_2. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Case 1: $n=-1$
Then we have
\begin{align*}
    I_0 &= \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-z_0} dz\\
    &=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{w(t)-z_0}w'(t)dt\\
    &=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(z_0 +re^{it})-z_0}(z_0+re^{it})'dt\\
    &=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{re^{it}}ire^{it}dt\\
    &=i \int_0^{2\pi} dt\\
    &= 2\pi i. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Comparing the real parts of (1) and (2), we conclude that $I_1 = 0$.

Case 2: $n \neq -1$
Note that in this case, $f$ has an antiderivative. Namely the map $F:\mathbb{C} - \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $F(z)=(z-z_0)^{n+1}/(n+1)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$. We conclude that
\begin{align*}
    I_0 &= 0. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Comparing the real parts of (1) and (3), we conclude that $I_1 = 0$.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: I checked on Wolfram Alpha!

Comment: Starting questions with "hello," or "I need help with the following question..." and other *filler* is a waste of everyone's time.  It isn't as annoying as posters who start "I have this question that I cannot answer and I'm hoping someone here can answer it..." and similar vapid and redundant remarks, but it is a step in that direction.

Comment: What does Wolfram Crapra say?

Comment: Well if you use $z_0=0, r=1, n=-1$, Wolfram gives $i \pi$.

Comment: To be honest, I give a crap what WA computes.

Comment: Dang, I need to eat crow.

Comment: $\operatorname{re} \int f dz $ and $\int (\operatorname{re}f )dz $ are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is $I_1$ is not necessarily real, roughly because the part $dz$ is complex.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, $I_0$ can be computed simply using the residue theorem or Cauchy integral formula.